# Is it safe to use LAST_INSERT_ID() in a system like Point of Sale

Tags: php, mysql, identity

Is it safe to use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in a system using `MySQL` like Point Of Sale when there are multiple users using the system at the same time?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the LAST_INSERT_ID() [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) it says:

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a
>   per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the
>   function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated
>   for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that
>   client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they
>   generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures
>   that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the
>   activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or
>   transactions.

So, if you call that function just after the insert to know the ID you inserted, it shouldn't be affeted by other concurrent users, as they are not using the same connection.

Anyway, there is not much detail in your question, so maybe your use case is a bit more complex than that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I thought mentioning `Point of Sale` would  give you a clear picture of what I wanted to mean or currently I am working on and that's why I skipped writing the details. Anyway you just solved my problem. Thanks :)

Comment: I am a bit surprised that numbers are maintained per-connection basis and not globally. Say, you have 2 connections and each started inserting numbers how could  these numbers be unique unless each connection has a different start value? Also, how can one get the correct value of the last number when issuing a query such as SELECT MAX(...) FROM ...?

Comment: The last_insert_id is maintained globally. But the number returned is related to the connection. In other words, if you insert three records and get the last insert id for each, you may get 456, 458 and 492 with other connections getting the numbers in between.

Comment: @EmmadKareem - if the LAST_INSERT_ID() returned the global most recently inserted value, it would be useless because you wouldn't know if that was the value you put in, or one someone else did. By having it return the LAST_INSERT_ID for the calling connection, it becomes a useful function - you can insert a row, then get it's id and go on using it for things.

Comment: @MichaelKohne +1, thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @Jaydee, +1, thanks for your explanation.